# No new version found. Upgrading 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 13.04

I have been trying to upgrade to 13.04 since the last two days. As advised on many other questions, I have removed the PPA and checked the repositories. As soon as I run `update-manager`, it searches for all the updates and then says `No new release found`. Why does this happen with every upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

What server do you use for fetching the upgrade? Maybe the new release is not available on that server.

In my case, I first tried a local server in my country ( as I do for every security fix) but that didn't work. I was denied access to some packages. Upgrade broke off.

Then I used the main server and everything was ok (and fast).